# Trace for multiple Camel Context

Tags: java, maven, jboss, apache-camel

I have two projects let's say - Project_1 and Project_2, and corresponding camel contexts, Configured as follows

```
<camel:camelContext id="project_1.context" trace="true">
        <camel:contextScan />
</camel:camelContext>

<camel:camelContext id="project_2.context" trace="true">
        <camel:contextScan />
</camel:camelContext>
```

with corresponding deployment units as project_1.jar, and project_2.jar, have been deployed in jboss.

But still I am not able to see traces for any of the CamelContext while starting my jboss.

log configuration for both projects are:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%c] %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=ALL
```

both projects have added the dependency for slf4j

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

both projects have added the module dependency for slf4j in jboss-deployment-structure:

```
<module name ="org.slf4j"/>
```

Kindly help me to let me know the thing that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your root logger is set as "Error".

In your project, if you have the messages logged in DEBUG or INFO mode, please try to change the root log level to "DEBUG" or "INFO" and verify